# Can CosmosDB be a simple key/value storage

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm new to CosmosDB and I need to store there some simple key/value pairs.

Is it mandatory to have a value of a collection a `json` format? If not, what can I mention as `partitionKey`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it mandatory to have a value of a collection a json format?

The short answer is yes, Cosmos DB is no-sql database which contains key-value structure document. The document has a flexible schema, de-normalized data, it can have mixed type of data such as a string value, number, array or an object. More details,please refer to this [guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/39421.azure-cosmos-db-designing-your-data-structure.aspx).

> If not, what can I mention as partitionKey?

Per my experience, when you design the partition key, you need to consider many factors.There is a nice paragraph [listed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#choose-partitionkey) here for your reference about choosing pk. My suggestion is that you could pick the most frequently queried column as pk.